# How to autofocus on the USD value when 3 values are entered in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-select

As mentioned above, how would I set the **focus on my USD value field** when the 1 of the 3 inputs are entered , or all 3? 
The code below currently displays the data from the 3 different type of fields (amount charged, currency and fysigned)

**CODE**

https://codesandbox.io/s/8zv2v5mr22

Thank you

Comment: when the 1 of the 3 inputs are entered , or all 3 - Can you explain this more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DOM Ref` for the USD value input field can be set and then used to control focus on it.

In the constructor for the `App` component, create a `Ref` field.

```
constructor(props) {
  //...
  this.USDValueInputRef = React.createRef();
  //...
}
```

For the USDValue `FormControl`, set `inputRef` prop  to the `Ref` created in constructor for the `App` component.

```
<FormControl
  type="text"
  defaultValue={this.state.USDValue}
  inputRef={this.USDValueInputRef}
/>
```

The where you check that the previous three field values are set, you can focus the USDValue input,

```
if (/* condition */) this.USDValueInputRef.current.focus();
```

**Bonus**:

You can move state updates from the `onChangeAmountCharged`, `handleChangeCurrency` and `handleChangeFYSigned` event handlers to `setUSDValue`.

```
onChangeAmountCharged(e) {
  this.setUSDValue({ AmountCharged: e.target.value })
}

handleChangeCurrency(e) {
  this.setUSDValue({ Currency: e.value })
}

handleChangeFYSigned(e) {
  this.setUSDValue({ FYSigned: e.value })
}
```

Then update the state in a single go in `setUSDValue`.

```
setUSDValue(params) {
  let currencyParams = { ...this.state, ...params };
  const { AmountCharged, Currency, FYSigned } = currencyParams;
  const completed = AmountCharged && Currency && FYSigned;

  if (completed) {
    currencyParams = {
      ...currencyParams,
      USDValue: `${AmountCharged} ${Currency} ${FYSigned}`
    };
  }
  this.setState(currencyParams, () => {
    if (completed) this.USDValueInputRef.current.focus();
  })
}
```